# I forked the "minimal mistakes" Jekyll template, but it does not look like the original

Tags: jekyll

As the guide said I forked: https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/

but the result does not look as original, here is the result: https://avidanyum.github.io/minimal-mistakes/, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used minimal-mistakes, but it seems like this is a template, so you only have the "skeleton" of the website: It is up to you to put content inside. The design and layout seem to be identical to the example website, but with the content being replaced to only contain minimal data. This is done on purpose, when you start a new website with minimal-mistakes you don't want to have to clean all the "useless" data/text/images before starting to put in your own content.

Comment: yes but i expected to see at least the same content as the original minimal-mistakes has not mine, for a start, i saw documentation says: https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/quick-start-guide/ https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/quick-start-guide/ so i did that but it still looks empty while the original github i cloned has lot of content..

Comment: I feel like there won't be any content. The point of the project, as I understand it, is to provide a template for a website. There wouldn't be any point in providing it with pre-made content. The official site is base on the template, but customised to contain data (the text and tutorials). When you fork the project, you don't want to have to clean-up all of that useless content, because YOUR website won't be about the minimal-mistakes project.

Comment: this https://github.com/avidanyum/minimal-mistakes/commit/57a4324fa04086ee8c035a6969d3c415f250e556 is commit also explained it to me:

Comment: @Wndrr your answer seems to have been truncated.  Since it has been accepted, can you complete it so that it is available for others?

Comment: Very weird ! I updated my answer. I couldn't remember what it was exactly so I gave one that is along the same lines. Never seen a stack overflow post get truncated ... does this happen often on webmasters ?